# PHP image still displaying after deleted

Tags: php

I'm using a long form to update advertisements in my database. I also use this form to delete images by pressing the delete button. The delete progress works fine, it removes the image's path from the database but the image is still displaying until I manually reload the page. I tried to echo a javascript reload code in the end of the isset method, but it keeps reloading infinitely.

My code:

```
// Delete image
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $delete_imageid = $_POST['imageid'];
    $stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $delete_imageid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: _"...but the image is still displaying until I manualy reload the page."_ - which is the idea of browsers. Unless you specifically tell it to reload a page, why wouldn't it keep displaying the page exactly as it was? And the code you shared has nothing to do with the issue - you said yourself that this works fine. What you need to show is how this action is triggered.

Comment: Just after deleting the image force browser to reload, i.e. by redirecting to the same location.

Comment: I tried to put ```echo '<script>location.reload();</script>';``` after stmt close, but it infinitely reloads the page.

Comment: Do you use AJAX for deleting? Or just PHP call? With this short code we don't know why you reached never ending loop. Add some more details/code samples, so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: It's just a simple PHP call in the same file as the form. There isn't any other code

Comment: Instead of sending `<script...` try to use `header(Location: your-desired-return-path-here); exit();` directly in PHP's condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a number of things fundamentally against PHP best practise:

1. You should not be deleting on a page which has HTML output. You should delete on a separate page that can only be accessed with an authentication mechanism (CSRF key or similar).
2. This `exit first page --> load new page --> reload first page` routine will also solve your issue of refreshment, so that your browser will need to load a PHP-only deletion page, before being silently redirected (as shown by [biesoir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424213/php-image-still-displaying-after-deleted#comment117430338_66424213)) back to your HTML display page. Thus the display page will refresh (due to reload).
3. *If* the display page is cached for some reason you can force the cache to be ignored by adding a timestamp to the call via `time()` function:

   ```
   header("Location: yoursite.com/your-desired-return-path-here?t=".time());
   exit;
   ```

---

Javascript is entirely unneeded as Javascript works on the Browser, while PHP works on the server. This is why you're entering an infinite loop because you're trying to continually check for a change at the browser end when PHP runs only on the server end.

These two things do not interact. The HTML and Javascript (*et al*) only work once the PHP has completed and sent the result to the remote browser.

> ```
> PHP/Server --> Javascript/HTML/Browser
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, I'll do it like that.

Comment: @randomdude glad to help `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you been trying http request after deletion code? It loads all page again. Similar to js setup, but sent straight frome your php code.

```
/***
 * Assuming this code is on the same page as yoursite.com/your_img_url
 * The header/exit should be within the if loop
 ***/
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $delete_imageid = $_POST['imageid'];
    $stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $delete_imageid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    //header("Location: yoursite.com/your_img_url=$_POST['imageid']"); EDITED
      header("Location: yoursite.com/your_url_where_you_removed_img");
    exit;
}
```

ofc yoursite.com/your_img_url is a url you are trying to reload
I always use that kind of reload after changing database and it is working well.
EDITED: ofc its depends how you build your site, but check for header("Location: ") usage in php and you will have fast and simple solution

Comment: Almost, that redirect should be within `if` condition, otherwise he'll reach redirects loop.

Comment: What good would placing the id of a deleted image in the url do? And by placing the `header` call outside the `if`, you're a) risking a redirection loop and b) probably going to get an "Undefined index" notice.

Comment: yes, sorry no need to use `$_POST['imageid']` in that case... i writed it by mistake becouse i have dynamically generated site with a lot of point of sell and i need to know what pos i'm editing `my_site?pos=$id`  and reloading pos site to see saved changes

Comment: @Martin i just left it becouse i was thinki'n removing it will disrespect in some way commented users who found this misatke and for consistency reason :) but i'll remember it for future, thanks

Comment: There is no need to do that. When you make an edit, it is visible in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66424397/revisions). So anyone who wants to know what the comments were referring to can click the "edited _[some time]_ ago" link at the bottom of your answer.